# Does my website have a SSL Issue?

Tags: openssl

I am trying to determine if an issue I am having is with my ssl certificate or something with one of my scripts.

I am using wordpress and trying to process a membership payment with the paypal express sandbox. I am getting the following error:

```
methodName_ failed: cURL error 35: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I have ran a test, using COMODO SSL Analyzer, on my url to try and verify things but I dont really know what Im doing here. [Comodo Test](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=https://thehostwiz.com)

Is there an openssl command I can use to verify if SSL is set up correctly on my site and then I can focus on the scripts or something else which may be causing my issue?

**UPDATE**

I was using classic godaddy hosting and have upgraded to cPanel hosting. SSL isnt even installed and things are working. Not sure what is different in the new server to reolve the issues, but the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Per my hosting this error is not caused by a bad ssl certificate. They are saying its a plugin or plugin configuration issue. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It is not clear from your question what the problem is, i.e. what this curl call is trying to do, which site does it access etc. If it is used to access some different site it might not be related to the certificate of your site at all. Apart from that your site shows a very bad grade C in [the SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=thehostwiz.com) which you should probably fix no matter what caused this specific error you are asking about.

Comment: I see that I have a C there, It might be time to change hosts, they have stated the only way I can get TLS 1.2 is upgrading to a dedicated server.

Beyond that I have clearly stated I am trying to process a Paypal payment and getting that error. This would mean I am trying to establish a connection with Paypal. I doubt the error is on their end.

Comment: Sorry that I did not know how exactly Paypal payments are processed and which processes and servers are involved there. Sorry that I got confused by your report of the HTTPS capabilities of your server even if these are irrelevant since you don't make a request to your site but to Paypal. And sorry that I don't know which TLS library in which version your are using in your curl call. But given how badly setup the system is it is not unlikely that the problem is that your OpenSSL version is too old to deal with Paypals requirements of TLS 1.2.

Comment: This is what I was thinking too. Needing to be TLS 1.2, but I started using a different plugin and I am able to process a payment with the Paypal Sandbox. For now I am either going to let this topic go. Thanks for your input, I appreciate it.

Comment: Upgraded my hosting and the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an openssl command I can use to verify if SSL is set up correctly on my site and then I can focus on the scripts or something else which may be causing my issue?

I prefer the testtool ssllabs.com, as it's easier to read than the Comodo test.

https://dev.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=thehostwiz.com

## Results

[image: Scan results]

- C is not a good grade (grade between A+ and F)
- Your cert is valid and well configured. It's SHA256 what is strongly advised.
- TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)   is insecure. This is really an issue. You need to fix your TLS config.
- SSL 2 and SSL 3 are disabled, that's good!
- TLS 1.1 and 1.2 aren't enabled, which is strongly advised

> I am using wordpress and trying to process a membership payment with the paypal express sandbox. I am getting the following error:
>
> ```
>    methodName_ failed: cURL error 35: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
> ```

The SSL 3 handshake fails as SSL 3 has been disabled. The tool should not use SSL 3, but TLS.

PS Had problems with www.ssllabs.com, so took dev.ssllabs.com

Comment: I pressed my hosting after evaluating the poor quality of security in my SSL and found I only had TLS 1.0, in order to get to 1.2 I needed to upgraded. I think your answer plus @symcbean's answer helped give me the push I needed to get my issue resolved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be occurring when your application makes an https call to the paypal site. If this is the case then it has nothing to do with the ssl *server* configuration and certificate on your webserver. It is a problem with the ssl client configuration.

This particular error means that your ssl client does not suport any of the cyphers available on the server. The sites listed elsewhere in answers will tell you what cyphers your server is configured to use. To find out what your client supports, write a test harness in php and retrieve the content of https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check

You should also check the code implemented in the site to check the cypher selection is not [restricted](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) there.

If that it is not overridden, then curl will be using the options defined in openssl's configuration.